# Is HTTP status 202 appropriate for account creation, while waiting for a confirmation code?

Tags: api, rest, http, http-status-codes

I have an API with a 2 step sign-up flow:

1. user requests a new account (`POST` with some account information in the body)
2. user confirms the account (`POST` with a verification code received via text or email)

I'm thinking the response status codes for these steps should be:

1. 202 Accepted
2. 201 Created

Is this an appropriate use of `202 Accepted`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this **might not** be an appropriate use of `202 Accepted`.

The response [`202 Accepted`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-202-accepted) indicates that the request has been accepted for processing by the server and that it can't be acted upon.

> The 202 (Accepted) status code indicates that the request has been accepted for processing, **but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon**, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place. There is no facility in HTTP for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous operation.
>
> The 202 response **is intentionally noncommittal**. Its purpose is to allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist until the process is completed. The representation sent with this response ought to describe the request's current status and point to (or embed) a status monitor that can provide the user with an estimate of when the request will be fulfilled.

So you might use `201 Created` (like [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7591#section-3.2) does) as you might be creating the `User` resource immediately when the user sends the `POST` request for registration. However, if your registration process is too complex or requires some background operations before you send the confirmation email/SMS you can still look into `202`.

See:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-202-accepted
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202
- https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9110.html#status.202
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-post

Comment: Thank you. I found it a bit unclear whether 202 applies to cases where the processing required would be initiated by the client. Based on your answer, I assume it does not?

Comment: Correct, it does not. 202 is sent when your service receives the request, and initiate a process mostly happening in the background, so the client only knows that there's something running, or initialised to run. In your case, the client knows that the resource is created, and it's only waiting for **the client's action**